# Await Buffer.from(String) turns out to numbers (Javascript)

Tags: arrays, async-await

i am trying desperately to solve the following problem. I researched a lot already but nothing really solved the problem (the used language is Javascript with Node.js and react-bootstrap library).

I want to write the following Array to Buffer and save it to IPFS in a way, that i can read it out later.

Nevertheless, the IPFS.Add() Method demand a buffer object, so i struggle to create the buffer object.

Here the array:

```
  const line_supplier = new Array({ 
                Lieferant: "Yello" , 
                Postleitzahl: "13752" , 
                Arbeitspreis: "5" , 
                Grundpreis: "10" , 
                Email: "email"
            });
```

Sounds pretty easy, i know. If i do it like this, the console shows me a an empty buffer.

```
         const line_buffer = await Buffer.from(line_supplier);
          console.log(line_buffer);
```

I also tried ..line_supplier[0], or the recommendations with ..'UTF-8' as offset. I also declared the array directly in Buffer.from(declaration).
Either way, i get an error or just a couple of numbers out. Maybe this is already the mistake. I expect the buffer to be readable like a string?
So i converted the line supplier to a string with

```
 const line_string = JSON.stringify(line_supplier);
```

But even with this string injected in Buffer.from(), i only get a Uint8Array(84) Object out with a lot of numbers.
I dont know what i am missing. It must be something very small. I read all the description of the methods already, but cant find it.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: please identify the used language.

Comment: Sorry, its Javascript with Node.js and react-bootstrap library.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, the following:

```
            const line_string = JSON.stringify(line_supplier);
            console.log(line_string);
            const line_buffer = await Buffer.from(line_string);
            console.log(line_buffer);
 await ipfs.add(line_buffer, (err, ipfsHash) => {
                console.log(err,ipfsHash);
```

Hence you get an array saved the way you want!